# Mysql limit per parent id

Tags: mysql, limit, where-clause

How can I limit result per each `id` in `WHERE` clause?
My query is:

```
SELECT name 
FROM location_areas 
WHERE parent IN ("1,2,3") 
ORDER BY popularity,name
```

Parent is not unique.

I need to get 10 results for each parent `id` in `WHERE` clause.

for example table structure is:

```
id   name   parent
1    name    0
2    name    1
3    name    1
4    name    80
5    name    80
6    name    80
7    name    80
8    name    1
```

Comment: put you table structue and it is easy.

Comment: I hope following link helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740071/is-there-a-way-to-limit-results-per-group-of-result-rows-in-mysql?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   T.name,
   T.popularity,
   T.parent,
   T.rank
FROM
(
SELECT
   L.name,
   L.popularity,
   L.parent,
   @rank := IF(@parent = parent, @rank + 1, 1) rank,
   @parent := parent
FROM location_areas L,
(SELECT @rank := 1, @parent := NULL) R
) T
WHERE T.rank <= 10
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT T.name, T.popularity, T.parent, T.level, T.rank
FROM (
         SELECT L.name, L.popularity,
             L.parent, L.level,
             @rank := IF(@parent = parent, @rank + 1, 1) rank,
             @parent := parent
         FROM location_areas L,
             (SELECT @rank := 1, @parent := NULL) R
         WHERE L.parent IN (".$ids.")
     ) T WHERE T.rank <= 10;
```

Comment: 'SELECT L.name, L.popularity, L.parent, @rank := IIF(@parent = parent' at line 7

Comment: I don't know why but it returns only one result per parent id.

Comment: Edited. I have missed `FROM` and need `IF` instead of `IIF`.

Comment: No itsnt trouble. i fix it. It returns only one result per parent id. WHERE T.rank <=10 not works. because it return only one row per parent without this.

Comment: Have you more than one record per parent in initial set?

Comment: I little correct your query because it not contains clause. My query is - `SELECT
   T.name,
   T.popularity,
   T.parent,
   T.level,
   T.rank
   FROM
   (
SELECT
   L.name,
   L.popularity,
   L.parent,
   L.level,
   @rank := IF(@parent = parent, @rank + 1, 1) rank,
   @parent = parent
FROM location_areas L WHERE L.parent IN (".$ids."),
(SELECT @rank := 1, @parent := NULL) R
) T WHERE T.rank <= 10");`

Comment: 1. You have cant put WHERE in subquery in this part of query. 2. `@parent = parent` must be `@parent := parent`.

Comment: Sorry. all works correctly. I see only one result because of error in my php script. Thank you so much for your help. Best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it lie this

```
SET @level = 0;
SET @group = '';

SELECT 
    name
FROM (
    SELECT 
        name ,
        parent
        @level := IF(@group = parent, @level+1, 1) AS level, 
        @group := parent as EGroup 
    FROM test
    WHERE parent IN ("1,2,3") 
    ORDER BY parent 
) rs
WHERE level < 11
```

Comment: This returns all results. not 10 per parent.