# mysql - unique records with UNION

Tags: mysql, group-by, unique, union

In a forum, the following query should extract 2 posts from each of 2 random and unique threads (represented by parent_id). How do I make sure the parent_id is indeed unique?

```
(SELECT parent_id, post_content, nickname FROM posts AS a JOIN users ON users.user_id=a.user_id JOIN

(SELECT parent_id AS c FROM posts LIMIT 1) AS b ON a.parent_id=b.c ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 2)

UNION ALL

(SELECT parent_id, post_content, nickname FROM posts AS a JOIN users ON users.user_id=a.user_id JOIN

(SELECT parent_id AS e FROM posts LIMIT 1) AS d ON a.parent_id=d.e ORDER by post_id DESC LIMIT 2)

ORDER BY RAND()
```

I tried adding group by and union distinct but  I keep getting records with the same parent_id..(unless I'm placing the group by in the wrong position).

Comment: What is the difference between these 2 queries ? may be there is another better solution for your scenario if you provide some more brief in your question regarding your criteria

Comment: Each of the two queries should get a unique couple of posts from a thread. Maybe the union is not needed at all here?

Comment: Can you use user defined variables in your query? like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987083/sql-return-100-random-rows-for-each-age/25987337#25987337

Comment: Hope this help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314940/mysql-limit-per-parent-id

Comment: It does! let me just try it out on my db

Comment: Works great! but how do I make sure the parent is random without specifying WHERE L.parent IN (".$ids.") as the answer mentions?

Comment: I don't try it on my db but I think you can use sub query such as `WHERE L.parent IN (SELECT parent FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND())`